# How to block packets received by eth0 from going up to TCP/IP stack

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module

We are using dev_add_pack with ETH_P_ALL to get copies of sk_buff of all ethernet frames received by eth1. Is there a way we can prevent eth1 from forwarding all the ethernet frames up to TCP/IP layer while still letting it capture all the frames and passing it on to our loadable kernel module?

Comment: Just found out that netem can be used to cause 100% packet loss like so:
        sudo tc qdisc add dev eth4 root netem loss 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a netfilter hook. Rather than dev_add_pack, which gets a copy of the sk_buff (thereby allowing the original sk_buff to propagate up to the TCP/IP stack, a netfilter hook will give you the pointer to the original sk_buff as it traverses the stack, and your code actually executes as callback from the stack itself - so you can choose to block the packet, claim ownership in your module, or do pretty much anything on your mind.

Comment: [The Netfilter Architecture of Linux 2.4](http://www.6test.edu.cn/~lujx/linux_networking/0131777203_ch19lev1sec3.html) This is useful!